# select * with column(s) from different table merging with that of original table's columns

Tags: sql, hsqldb

These are my tables(with some records):

```
Product:
ID PRICE NAME    DESCRIPTION
1  100   laptop  laptop_desc
2  200   mouse   mouse_desc
3  300   伊吾    伊吾伊吾

Product_Translations:
PID  LANG NAME DESCRIPTION
1    ch   伊吾  伊吾伊吾
```

And using the following query I could JOIN the 2 tables:

```
SELECT p.id,p.price,
      COALESCE(pt.Name, p.Name) Name, 
      COALESCE(pt.Description, p.Description) Description
FROM Product p
LEFT JOIN Product_T pt 
ON pt.PID = p.ID 
AND pt.LANG = 'ch'   
WHERE (UPPER(p.name) LIKE UPPER('%伊吾%') OR UPPER(pt.name) LIKE UPPER('%伊吾%'))
```

Now my question is that in the above query I need to mention each and every column in the select query explicitly(like p.id, p.price; real table has lot more columns) which I  don't want to  do. In my case I need to get all columns all the time, i.e, `select *`. But If give `p.*` in the query, name and description columns are coming twice which is expected(from Product and Product_T tables).  So is there any way I could still give p.* and get the merged name and description columns ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You could query the schema to find the columns on your tables and then dynamically build your select statement from that. (E.g. if a column with the same name appears in both tables only select it from one of them).

See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/databaseobjects-chapt.html#dbc_information_schema for information on how to query the schema in hsqldb.

Comment: As I'm using ORM , anyway I  know what are all columns are there in the table, but I don't want to specifically mention them in the select query. I need a SQL way of the getting my job done. Let me know if there is any solution.

Comment: If you do not want duplicate columns for `Name` and `Description`, there is no other way in SQL than naming each column that you want.

Comment: If you're using an ORM why do you need to write any explicit SQL? Shouldn't these tables be represented by two separate classes with some sort of join between them? What does it matter if the description is on both of them (except for the fact it means your schema isn't normalised)?

Comment: Though I'm using ORM, for this particular case I need to write native query(because of some other reason) which should retrieve all the columns. And of course, I'm doing JOIN between(see my query one more time). If you know the answer to my original question let me know.